# Creating entity in Rules causes PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry

Tags: entities, rules

My application based on CRM-Core.
I am using several [rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) which launch on the event "After saving a new crm core contact" and each has a crm_core_activity entity created as the rule's action.

Is it possible that the rules happen simultaneously which causes SQL error - trying to set same activity_id (which is primary key)?

Here is the error:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '879' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO {crm_core_activity} (activity_id, revision_id, uid, type, title, created, changed, uuid) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 879 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 1552 [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => email [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => תודה שפנית אלינו! [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => 1465830228 [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => 1465830228 [:db_insert_placeholder_7] => 4e87b796-fc8d-49f4-85f4-9ac944563576 ) in drupal_write_record() (line 7316 of /home/roi/sites/staging/0108-ormil/drupal-7.38/includes/common.inc).
```

The error happens randomly which makes me think this is a timing issue between multiple rules on the same trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I created an entity using code (implementing hook_rules_action_info()). In the hook I created a new entity and also saved it.
In the rule I both called this hook implementation (create+save an entity) and also explicitly saved it is a rules action.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [issue # 430274](https://www.drupal.org/node/430274), which explains that "after saving something" actually happens ... "before saving something" (which is not a bug, simply how the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module  works ...).

A possible compromise to avoid these kind of issues, is to transform what's you're trying to do into a Rules Component, so that your original Rule "schedules the execution" (using the Rules Scheduler submodule) of that Rules Component (eg after only a few secs or mins later on ... if your cron job runs frequent enough, if not it'll be next time cron runs). This compromise will ensure that at the time the Rules Component is executed, the entity is for sure saved ... (so that can't be the reason anymore then why things don't work as expected ...).

**Note**: it's tough (virtually impossible) to pinpoint what exactly is causing your issue without knowing what exactly those rules look like. Adding a copy of your exported rules to the question may possibly help, but still. However, I'd recommend you to do some Rules debugging, using any of the techniques I described in my answer to [How can I display the value of a variable inside a condition?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199080/rules-debug-how-can-i-display-the-value-of-a-variable-inside-a-condition/199134#199134)

Comment: Which entity, in this case, do you think launching the rule 'before saving'? I also thought of scheduling components to avoid the simultaneous creation of entities, but I can't see the launching before or after should matter.
I also don't understand why the SQL 'insert' statement explicitly dictates the id (the primary auto increment key) and not letting mysql do it's part of autoincrementing.

Comment: @roi : See the "note" I added to my answer, I'm afraid debugging in your own environment is about the only thing you can do. Turn on the Rules Evaluation Log and check if what you see being executed, matches with your expectations (if not you may get a clue what's wrong).