# Combining AND and OR in Rules

Tags: 7, rules

I'm trying to set up a rule (using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module) with AND and OR conditions.
I have a content type with a field A (date) and field B (time slot).

The rule needs to check if field A is either e.g. a Monday or a Wednesday AND if the time slot in field B is either 16:00 or 17:00 or 18:00 or 19:00 (on a Monday) OR 13:00 or 14:00 or 15:00 or 16:00 (on a Wednesday).

If it meets those criteria it has to perform an action.

I've set up my rule as shown in the screenshot, but alas whatever combination or indentation I use, it won't work ...

Who can shed some light on this? Much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I think you only need one "OR" and 8 "AND"s: (Monday AND 16:00) OR (Monday AND 17:00) OR ... OR (Wednesday AND 15:00) OR (Wednesday AND 16:00). *Or* have I misunderstood your situation?

Comment: Hey b@Jeroen , I think your comment might also work, though you'd be testing "Is it Monday" 4 times (I think), What your comment doesn't say is how the "indents" should like (as you must know: crucial to get it to work). Why not post an answer similar to mine (feel free to copy/past my layout I used and adapt it to what you suggested). If you do, and assuming both answers are correct, Colin is going to have a hard time to select which one to "accept", no?

Comment: Merci for your (late) accept of my answer ... So what's next, no other Rules-related questions anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 extra ANDs, right below the highest level (1st) OR.

And EACH of the 2 ORs you already have, and the Data comparison that preceeds those ORs, you need to move them below the extra AND. So that in the end it looks like so:

- OR
- - AND
- - - Data Comparison (A=Maandag)
- - - OR
- - - - Text Comparison (B=16:00)
- - - - Text Comparison (B=17:00)
- - - - Text Comparison (B=18:00)
- - - - Text Comparison (B=19:00)
- - AND
- - - Data Comparison (A=Woensdag)
- - - OR
- - - - Text Comparison (B=13:00)
- - - - Text Comparison (B=14:00)
- - - - Text Comparison (B=15:00)
- - - - Text Comparison (B=16:00)

Here is how "I" would translate the above logic:

- We accept a date that is either on Monday (line 2 to 8) OR (line 1) Wednesday  (line 9 to 15).
- If you want a date that is a Monday (= line 3), we insist (via the AND in line 2) that you pick a timeslot that fits for us on Monday.
- To pick a timeslot for Monday, you have a choice (OR in line 4) of 4 options (ie those in line 5, 6, 7 or 8).
- Similar [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), oeps rules, apply for Wednesday, as expressed in line 9 to 15.

If after these changes your Rules Action(s) still don't get executed (because something else is wrong in any of these Rules Conditions, and/or you're not using an appropriate Rules Event), then move on to [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) **debugging**, as explained in "[How can I display the value of a variable inside a condition?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199080/rules-debug-how-can-i-display-the-value-of-a-variable-inside-a-condition/199134#199134)".

PS: just to make sure your "*Text Comparison*" condition behaves as you expect/hope it to do, create a temporary clone of your rule with only 1 Rules Condition (= 1 such text comparison), with same Rules Event and same Rules Action. That way you can either narrow down your problem, or exclude that as a possible reason why it still doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, seems logic now when I see it. But ... it doesn't seem to work. When I choose monday, no matter what time, it still evaluates as false. "The condition data_is evaluated to FALSE "