# 'Access denied' to Content Type

Tags: users

I've a website that I didn't build that is giving me some trouble. A whole Content Type is returning "access denied" error when authenticated users try to view it (Guests can).
The access is only denied when a field is set to 1, but the are no dependencies set. I really can't figure out from who the access is beeing denied.

I didn't find any access content modules.

Has somebody any ideas?

Comment: Could be a lot of things. Is Rules installed? Is there a custom module doing something weird? Is there code in template.php that looks weird?

Comment: 'rules' module is installed but how could the 'Rules' module affect the visibility of a content type? I only see create, edit and delete option....

Comment: You would be looking at any enabled Rules and see what their conditions and actions are. Specifically one like, when on node type FOO, if user role is X, do Y.

Comment: The only Rules that I have are rules that edit the mailing options. There is gotta be something else. Is there perhaps a way to see what is the cause of a access denied error on drupal?

Comment: Another thing to look for would be any workflow/workbench sort of state moderation... but it is really hard to tell. Could you update your question with a list of modules in the site? Something might jump out.

Answer (score 1):

From the limited details provided in your question, it could very well be that one of your enabled rules (created with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module) is what is causing your issue.

To actually confirm, for sure, if it is any of the enabled rules, use these steps:

- Disable of all your enabled rules. If the problem persists, you can be sure it is not because of a custom rule (don't forget to re-enabe the temporary disabled rules). If the problem is gone, continue with the next step to find which rule is causing your problem.
- Re-enable your temporary disabled rules, but only 1 at a time, and check if your problem comes back (each time after you re-enabled one more rule). At some point your problem should come back. As soon as that happens, the most recent re-enabled rule is what is causing your issue. In that case, re-enabe the remaining temporary disabled rules and continue with the next step.
- If you cannot find out what the actual problem might be in the re-enabled rule that causes the problem, move on to [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) **debugging**, as explained in my answer to "[How can I display the value of a variable inside a condition?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199080/rules-debug-how-can-i-display-the-value-of-a-variable-inside-a-condition/199134#199134)".

After you're sure it's not [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) causing the problem, I'd consider the "Workflow" module (which you also seem to be using) as the next suspect on my list. As a quick test (to see if that's the direction to go for further debugging), temporary disable the Workflow module: if the problem remains, then it is not the Workflow module either (don't forget to re-enable it afterwrds).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but it isn't the Rules module. It currently has just 2 rules and none of them touches the content type that it is being blocked.

Comment: Sorry to question your last comment  but rom the limited extra info provided, I'm not yet convinced it is not because of those 2 rules. Which Rules EVENTS are those 2 rules using? And what do you mean by "touches the content type"?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, but I'm pretty new to Drupal. The only two rules are in a workflow and they manage:
- Emails sent when registering
- A bypass of a process sending content to the website