# Why does my Rules Action about booking a time slot appear to not be executed?

Tags: 7, rules, bookings

I recently installed the [Booking time slot](https://www.drupal.org/project/booking_timeslots) module and got it to work as expected.

The issue I have is that its "Rules event" does not trigger a Rules Action. Here is my rule (for now it only includes a Rules Action to show a Drupal message):

```
{ "rules_booking" : {
"LABEL" : "Booking",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "entity" ],
"ON" : { "booking_insert" : [] },
"DO" : [ { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "Success!" } } ] } }
```

I have tried using various events (After saving a new booking, After updating an existing booking) but none appears to work.

I wondering if anyone has had this kind of experience or knows what could be wrong.

#### Update

Here is a screenshot of the Rules Events I can select:

[image]

Comment: I have edited the question to include the rules export format. Don't get what you mean by D5.

Comment: By D5 he meant version of Drupal.

Comment: Have you tried https://www.drupal.org/project/appointment_calendar module.
And also check the event which triggers rule to add booking slot and debug there if possible

Comment: I tried to debug. No debugging information is logged in the system log for my rule above. But when i change the event to e,g "when comment is deleted", the rule is fired and debugging is logged

Answer (score 0):

I'm about sure that the answer to your question can be found [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2633112).
And to be 100%, I recommend you do some [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) **debugging**, as explained in the answer to "[How can I display the value of a variable inside a condition?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199080/rules-debug-how-can-i-display-the-value-of-a-variable-inside-a-condition/199134#199134)".

#### Update

Your (1st) comment confirms what I wrote in my answer even more. Have a look at the [source code](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/booking_timeslots/tree/) and let me know where I can find more details about any of those "Various events" that you try to use are actually coded. I trust they are somewhere (since your question says you use them), but with my limited knowledge of Rules (hm, hm) I cannot find them ... in the typical ".inc* file where the Rules module expect them to be located. But since "I" cannot find them, it may well be that that also explains why the Rules module cannot find them ...

Comment: Question is D7. I tried to debug. No debugging information is logged in the system log for my rule above. But when i change the event to e,g "when comment is deleted", the rule is fired and debugging is logged.

Comment: @seyi your prior confirms what I wrote in my answer even more. Have a look at [the source code](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/booking_timeslots/tree/) and let me know **where** I can find more details about any of those "Various events" that you try to use are actually coded. I trust they are somewhere (since your question says you use them), but with my *limited* knowledge of Rules I cannot find them ... in the typical ".inc* file where the Rules module expect them to be located. PS: since "I" cannot find them, it may well be that that also explains why the Rules module cannot find them, get it?

Comment: Interesting. I also checked and its not in the booking slot module. Do you have any idea where the rules are coming from? I have updated the question to include a screenshot of the rules events.