# Unpublish node based on date field with Rules

Tags: 7, rules

I'm trying to unpublish a node based on a date field with Rules.
I've followed [this tutorial](https://rakeshwebdev.wordpress.com/2015/04/07/using-rules-to-publishunpublish-based-on-a-date-field-in-drupal/) but somehow it doesn't seem to work.

Here's my Component:

```
{ "rules_unpublish_termin" : {
    "LABEL" : "Unpublish Termin",
    "PLUGIN" : "action set",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : { "node" : { "label" : "node", "type" : "node" } },
    "ACTION SET" : [ { "node_unpublish" : { "node" : [ "node" ] } } ]
  }
}
```

And here's the Rule:

```
{ "rules_unpublish_termin_rule" : {
    "LABEL" : "Unpublish Termin Rule",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "rules_scheduler" ],
    "ON" : { "node_insert--termin" : { "bundle" : "termin" } },
    "IF" : [ { "node_is_published" : { "node" : [ "node" ] } } ],
    "DO" : [
      { "schedule" : {
          "component" : "rules_unpublish_termin",
          "date" : [ "node:field-termin-datum:value" ],
          "identifier" : "Unpublish content ID [node:nid] ([node:title]).",
          "param_node" : [ "node" ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm fairly new to Drupal and I've never used the Rules module so I'm not sure if there's something else I'm missing here.

*edit:*
I've been looking into it a bit more.
Currently I have 3 nodes in this bundle with the following dates:
2018-01-09 (which should have been unpublished today)
2018-05-12
2018-07-14

In the Tab **Schudule** under admin/config/workflow/rules/schedule I can see that the component `rules_unpublish_termin` has a **Schedule Date** for 2018-07-14 00:00 which would correlate with the very last date, this seems a bit odd..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. Timing of a scheduled Rules Component

After a rule is scheduled (using the Rules Scheduler, a submodule of Rules), it will only actually *execute* **next time cron runs**. Example:

- schedule a rule to execute at `timestamp X` (which appears to be `node:field-termin-datum:value` in your case).
- if the next time that cron runs is at `Y mins after timestamp X`, then the Rules execution will only happen then (= at `Y mins after timestamp X`).

BTW, as per the edit of your question, it seems that the Rules Component actually does get scheduled, and that your real issue is related to the execution of that scheduled component ... read on for more details about that.

#### 2. Cron runs anonymous

Cron (always) runs with user anonymous, rest assured about that (in any Drupal 7 site). But here is an "*educated*" guess: your site is configured so that anonymous users are NOT allowed (= do not have the permission) to unpublish nodes.

Up to you to confirm if my guess is correct, but if it indeed applies, the answer to your question is that to get this to work you *would need* to grant anonymous users the permission to unpublish nodes. I bet it is not going to be what you *want* to do (I wouldn't ...), but trust me, *that* would be a prereq to make it all work in your site.

#### 3. If everything else fails ...

If none of the above helps to find out what is causing your issue, then try either of these suggestions to get a better understanding of what is (not?) happening:

- Try to execute your Rules Component "manually" (just to test), to unit-test if it works as desired, so without using the Rules Scheduler. To do so, use the "execute" link to the right of the Rules Component (in the Rules UI).
- Do some [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) debugging ... For way more details about that, refer to the [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/199134/39516) to "[How can I display the value of a variable inside a condition?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/199080/39516)".

Comment: Thanks, Pierre! I just edited my question to add a detail, maybe this helps to discover the issue here. I'm just trying to debug my rule. Though even after running Cron manually it didn't unpublish my node.

Comment: @nihilistenhymne as per your edit of your question, I also further improved my answer. I'm about sure item "2." of my answer is going to be the actual answer to your question ... at least an explanation for why it is not working as you would want to. Let me know ...

Comment: thank you for your valuable answers! I've been looking through it again and is it possible that because of `"IF" : [ { "node_is_published" : { "node" : [ "node" ] } } ],` this Rule only applies for nodes that are created and published after I created the Rule?

Comment: hey @nihilistenhymne, the logic described in your question, will only apply to termin-nodes that (a) were created (= your Rules *Event*) ***AND*** (b) with status published  (= your Rules *Condition*) **AFTER** you enabled your Rule (and for as long as you leave the Rule enabled). I.e. only for such nodes your Rules Component (to unpublish them) will be scheduled (to run at the specified date). You remember since when your Rules is "active"? Also: what is the creation date of each of those 3 nodes?

Comment: Pierre, you saved me, thank you. I didn't understand the Conditions to this extend.

Comment: @nihilistenhymne aha, looks like you (we?) figured it out ... merci for the accept! Next (Rules related?) question?